# Замена сигнатур в приложениях с помощью Python

Tags: python, pip, signature

Можно ли как-то заменить одну сигнатуру на другую (как в cheat engine, например) используя этот язык? Может какая-то библиотека в pip?

Comment: Смотря что за сигнатуры вы хотите заменять. Можно просто регулярные выражения использовать.